# Database of Complete list of major cities in usa

Tags: database

I have to create a database with three tables

one for country then State and cities

My Country table is ok.

But i want to include all states of america to my state table and all major cities of each state in america to my city table.

i want any such database so that i can import my database

i need only major cities.

is there a site i can download or copy any such things , exactly as per my requirement

Please help me i'm not finding it in the exact way..

Thanks

Comment: Please define "major".  Also, please explain why Aaron's suggestion doesn't fit the bill.  Besides the rudeness of your blunt "no" it doesn't give us any clues about what you want instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is Free but you may end up writing a converter code or something to transfer the whole list into Database.

http://www.census.gov/tiger/tms/gazetteer/places2k.txt

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you could find something with a web search; e.g. "database major cities USA".  For example, I found [this](http://www.presentationmall.com/shop/item.asp?itemid=5) in the first page of search results ... if you can afford to invest $20.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a list of US Cities with a population greater than 100,000 people.  Does that meet your definition of "major"?  If so, [check it out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_United_States_cities_by_population).